# How to make Intellj Idea write dependencies into POM files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I use Project Structure - Libraries to install dependencies while coding, then Shift+F10 for test runs, and it works fine. But when I use Maven - package to package the project, it won't work because of missing dependencies in POM files. What I'm doing now is to copy-paste every dependencies into POM file for the final packaging, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do that, or maybe a better way to package a Springboot project into a jar file?

Comment: Why aren't you adding the dependencies to the pom in the first place? Dependency management one of the best features of maven.

Comment: @f1sh it's just easier to search the name and select a version than open the browser and search on maven, plus i have some global libraries in place that can be put into a new project with a single click.

Comment: but when you have to add the dependencies to the maven pom anyways, why do you take the step in between? That makes it clearly not "just easier".

Comment: @f1sh it's not a thing when you spent months on a project, adding denpendencies along the way and port them in the end. but i'm working on some smaller projects now and these things became a task for me. i'm hoping for a way to keep the convienency on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the **Dependencies tool window** is what you are asking for. This is a IntelliJ tool that let you search among dependencies and add a new dependency to the pom-file by clicking a button. It is available at **View | Tool Windows | Dependencies.**
See this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/package-search.html) for more info
[image]